# Installing PostgreSQL is creating empty data folder

Tags: postgresql, windows

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL form ToolShed on my windows machine.
Everytime I run the intaller as admin it fails with errors.

> ```
> Failed to load SQL modules into the database cluster.
> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly 
> Error reading file C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/data/postgresql.conf
> ```

I see the C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/data folder is empty.
So I execute initdb, which is loading data folder with some files
and try to start server using

```
pg_ctl -D C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/data -l logfile start
```

I get below error.

> ```
> waiting for server to start....Access is denied.
> stopped waiting
> pg_ctl: could not start server
> ```

Tried v11/13/15 same issue with all of them.

Thanks

Comment: try creating an empty file named postgresql.conf in the data folder? looks like toolshed isn't doing this right

Comment: don't put the data directory into `c:\Program Files`, `%ProgramData%` (typically `C:\ProgramData`) is a better choice. Also make sure any anti-virus is disabled for the Postgres data directory.